# how to import googlesource projects in to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, import

I'm new to Gradle and Android Studio and I've been struggling to import any of the projects under https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ in to AS and successfully run it on my dev device. I'm trying to get the Launcher3 running and I get all kinds of different errors. I think I'm missing some major parts on how to configure the studio and Gradle maybe?

What is the proper procedure? 
I installed Latest Gradle and AS. Cloned the project from Git. Imported to AS and then I get errors like this or that version of Gradle is required, main activity cant be found, gradle plugin can't be found etc. Tried changing Gradle version in config file. Tried setting my local Gradle download in build settings etc.

Cheers,
Hamed

Update:
I changed the version to 2.1.2 here:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:2.1.2'
    }
```

and currently I get the error:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:2.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-gradle-plugin/2.1.2/protobuf-gradle-plugin-2.1.2.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-gradle-plugin/2.1.2/protobuf-gradle-plugin-2.1.2.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-gradle-plugin/2.1.2/protobuf-gradle-plugin-2.1.2.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-gradle-plugin/2.1.2/protobuf-gradle-plugin-2.1.2.jar
Required by:
    :Launcher3:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have confused the build tools version for the protobuf-gradle-plugin version.
The latest protobuf-gradle-plugin version is 0.8.2, as seen [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle).

try changing it to:
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'